# How can i upgrade geoserver on a geonetwork install?

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

I have a default geonetwork install with Jetty and geoserver but i would like to upgrade to the latest (unstable) build of geoserver instead of the stable version it comes with.

Any ideas how i can do this?

I don't mind reinstalling everything from scratch if i have to.

I'm running Windows Server 2008r2 sp1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to fetch the latest war file and unpack it in the webapps folder. The easiest way is to stop jetty and delete the geoserver directory and then use zip7 (or similar) to unpack the war file (make sure it ends up in a directory called geoserver).

If you have not moved the data directory from it's default position you will want to do that first. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html explains how to do this.

Comment: can you elaborate on the part about moving the data directory from it's default position?

Comment: added a link to the answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks! i was looking everywhere for a config file.